# Existe alguma diferença entre a chamada "str(my_object)" e "my_object.__str__()" em Python?

Tags: python

Eu observei que, no Python, quando temos um objeto com o método `__str__`, ele é responsável por retornar uma string que represente o objeto - ou alguma coisa parecida com isso.

Exemplo:

```
from uuid import uuid4
uuid4().__str__()
```

A saída é:

```
36cdc126-9d4d-43f9-9ede-bef8e15b834c
```

Porém, o mesmo se dá com a chamada de `str` passando esse mesmo objeto como parâmetro.

```
str(uuid4())
```

A saída é:

```
 36cdc126-9d4d-43f9-9ede-bef8e15b834c
```

Tenho algumas perguntas a respeito disso:

- Existe alguma diferença entre a chamada do método `__str__` (`my_object.__str__()`em relação à achamada de `str` (`str(my_object)`)?
- O método `__str__` é utilizado pela função `str`?
- Levando em consideração as boas práticas que devo aplicar à linguagem, qual das duas formas eu devo utilizar para retornar o objeto como string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Existe alguma diferença entre a chamada do método `__str__` (`my_object.__str__()` em relação à chamada de `str` (`str(my_object)`)?

Não. [Segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), `str()` chama `objeto.__str__()`.

> O método `__str__` é utilizado pela função `str`?

Sim.

> Levando em consideração as boas práticas que devo aplicar à linguagem, qual das duas formas eu devo utilizar para retornar o objeto como string?

[`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str). Ela se encarrega de produzir a formatação adequada para a saída em questão.

Comment: Você usa o `#` para representar minhas perguntas. Você não acha que o `>` ficaria melhor?

Comment: Tanto faz. Se quiser editar, fique à vontade.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez acho que você deveria rever a formatação que você faz em suas respostas, o uso de `#` faz sentido em uma resposta mais extensa com subtítulos, do jeito atual cria poluição visual tornando difícil a leitura. Pense que sua resposta é como se fosse um documento a ser entregue a um cliente ou professor de faculdade, não estou dizendo pra seguir as normas ABNT, mas esse seu padrão atual de usar `#` não é bom.

Comment: @Orion Sinceramente, não vejo essa poluição visual de que você fala, mas posso sim substituir os sinais, sem problemas.

Comment: pow cara, você não vê a poluição nesse post? tá poluído pra caramba!!

Answer (score 3):

Respondendo as perguntas tais quais apresentadas:

- Existe alguma diferença entre a chamada do método **str** (my_object.**str**()em relação à achamada de str (str(my_object))?

  > Na maioria dos casos, não. Contudo, algumas implementações de python podem apresentar desempenho diferente entre o uso da função genérica str(OBJECT) e OBJECT.__ str__(), devido ao uso implícito de otimizações. Quando na dúvida, use a função genérica da linguagem (str(OBJECT)).
- O método __ str__ é utilizado pela função str?

  > Sim. Parte do design básico da linguagem Python impede a criação de métodos inacessíveis dentro de módulos. Contudo, pelas convenções PEP, métodos que não devem ser usados por outros módulos (métodos em JAVA denominados "protected") tem seu nome precedido e suscedido por duas underscores ( __ NOME__ ).
- Levando em consideração as boas práticas que devo aplicar à linguagem, qual das duas formas eu devo utilizar para retornar o objeto como string?

  > Pelas convenções PEP, ao colocar dois underscores ao redor do nome de um método, um programador está sugerindo aos demais que tal método não deveria ser usado fora do escopo da implementação do objeto no qual está definido. Assim, as melhores práticas sugerem o uso de str(OBJECT) para retornar um método como string.

Answer (score 1):

À parte das outras duas respostas, que estão corretas, vale a pena mencionar que a implementação padrão de `__str__` - que fica na classe `object`, de onde todos os objetos Python derivam, faz uma chamada À função `__repr__`: ou seja, se sua classe não definir `__str__` mas definir `__repr__`, a saída dessa última é o que é devolvido quando se chama `str(seu_obj)`. Se você redefine a prórpia `str` pode ter uma `repr` e uma  `str` distintos.

Python apresenta a forma `repr` em adição á `str` como uma visualização do objeto que é mais conveniente em ambientes interativos - como o terminal Python ou o prompt de debug.  Por exemplo, para strings em si, a saída `str` é exibida sem aspas, enquanto que o `repr` inclui as aspas, e mostra alguns caractéres unicode na form de escape `'\uHHHH'` em vez dos caractéres em si. (Em Python 2.x, todos os caractéres não ASCII eram exibidos em uma forma escapada com `\xHH`)